# Calculating all unique combinations of ArrayList<<ArrayList<String>> of desired length n in Java

Tags: java

I would like to calculate all possible unique combinations of ArrayLists of ArrayLists of String of desired length n. If the ArrayList of String has only 1 object (a string) at each position, is easy. But how calculate when there are multiple objects at each position? Example, calculate all unique combinations of length 2. We are allowed to take only 1 object from each position.

```
1. A, b
2. C
3. D    Answer is [a,c], [a,d], [b,c], [b,d], [c,d].
```

A naive solution would be to create combinations of length 3 [a, c, d], [b, c, d] and for each of these, create all combinations and discard the duplicate ones. In the above example, the combination [c, d] appears 2 times.Another example: Position 1: a, b Position 2: c, d Position 3: e We have a max length of 3, since we have 3 positions.We must calculate all unique combinations of length 2.Naive solution algorithm: Make all combinations of max length (that is 4 combinations, [a, c, e], [a, d, e], [b, c, e], [b, d, e] ) Set S = null For each of those combinations [
    generate all possible combinations of desired length.

```
 if the combination doesn't belong to set S then add it to set S
      else
    move to next combination ]
```

In my example: First, I take [a, c, e]. Combinations of length 2 are `[a,c], [a,e], [c,e]`. None of them belongs to S, so I add them to it, `S = [ [a,c], [a,e], [c,e] ]`. Next is [a, d, e] Combinations of length 2 are `[a,d], [a,e], [d,e]` I look carefully, [a, e] already belongs to S, so I add only [a, d] and [d, e]

```
S
= [[a,c], [a,e], [c,e], [a,d], [d,e]]
```

And so on. Is there another way of calculating without having to compare it every time against S?

Answer (score 1):

Use backtracking with a recursive function. This function gets the position within the outer list, the current intermediate result and some Consumer for the final results. In every step this function either:

- adds the current result to the consumer and returns, if the current result has the desired length
- adds one member of the current inner list to the current result and calls itself with the next element of the outer list

Keep care of the edge cases, they should probably lead to an immediate return.

Edit: for example like this:

```
package net;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class Combinator {

    public <T> List<List<T>> combine(List<List<T>> elements, int length) {
        List<List<T>> result = new LinkedList<>();
        combine(elements, List.of(), length, result::add);
        return result;
    }

    private <T> void combine(List<List<T>> elements, List<T> curIntermediate, int length, Consumer<List<T>> resultReceiver) {
        // result has desired length -> add it to the set of results
        if (curIntermediate.size() == length) {
            resultReceiver.accept(curIntermediate);
            return;
        }

        // no more elements to choose from -> nothing to do
        if (elements.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        // choose an element from the current inner list, add it to the intermediate result and proceed
        List<List<T>> subList = elements.subList(1, elements.size());
        for (T curInner : elements.get(0)) {
            LinkedList<T> newIntermediate = new LinkedList<>(curIntermediate);
            newIntermediate.add(curInner);
            combine(subList, newIntermediate, length, resultReceiver);
        }

        // choose not to add an element from the current outer and proceed
        combine(subList, curIntermediate, length, resultReceiver);
    }
}
```